# How to persist a MongoDB cursor in between requests?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, node.js, mongodb, web-applications

In the contest of a web server:

In order to avoid re-querying (using `find`), one could try and keep between requests the cursor reference returned by `find`. The `Cursor` object is a complex object storing for example socket connections. How to store such an object to avoid re-querying on subsequent web requests? I am working in Node.js but any advice is helpful (regardless of the language: rails, C#, Java, PHP).

(I am using persistent sessions)

Comment: Since the cursor returns in small batches defined by the 16meg limit of a document I am unsure how useful storing a reference to the cursor is, in fact it might be micro-optimisation since you would only be avoiding 16meg of results before you would have to requery again

Comment: Are cursors of any help in web apps that have to display a query result? I am thinking about scenarios like Twitter stream or Facebook news feed where you have in "infinite" stream or items.

Comment: well yes, all query results come back as cursors, both server-side and client side, the client cursor object is a representation of the servers own. I am still not following how useful it would be for a facebook feed or a twitter feed. I presume you would probably show at least 16 meg of result on the first page, when you go to ajax get more you would simply allow a new cursor to be made, most likely the old one already being gced by that point. Keeping track of that could be more work than just requerying.

Comment: Why would you need to store the cursor when the PHP driver already does it for you?  that's how you are able to "getmore" documents (i.e. fetch the next batch) Can you describe your exact use case?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky He means between scripts, so imagine you have a cursor in filea but want to use it, without making a new cursor, in fileb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook and Twitter's stream features are more complex than a simple query to a db. Systems like this tend to have two major backend components in their architecture, serving you data: slow and fast.

1) The first backend system is your database, accessed via a query to get a page of results from the  stream (being someone's twitter feed or their fb feed). When you page to the bottom or click 'more results' it will just increment the page variable and query against the API for that page of your current stream.

2) The 2nd is a completely separate system that is sending realtime updates to your page via websockets or paging against an API call. This is the 'fast' part of your architecture. This is probably not coming from a database, but a queue somewhere. From this queue, handlers are sending your data to your page, which is a subscriber.

Systems are designed like this because, to scale enormously, you can't depend on your db being updated in real time. It's done in big batches. So, you run a very small subset of that data through the fast part of your architecture, understanding that the way the user gets it from the 'fast' backend may not look exactly how it will eventually look in the 'slow' backend, but it's close enough.

So... moral of the story:

You don't want to persist your db cursor. You want to think 1) do I need updates to be realtime 2) and if so, how can I architect my system so that a first call gets me most of my data and a 2nd call/mechanism can keep it up to date.

Comment: When considering MongoDB secondaries could easily be used to scale stale reads from a database instead of a queue. As such this could be done completely from the database, so storing the pointer to a cursor is valid it is just micro-optmisation and probably not needed tbh

Comment: Are you sure MongoDB is single threaded? And also that cursor work that way?